# accepting input using check_box in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I'm a beginner working my way through a rails tutorial. An assignment consists of adding questions to a page (which can be edited and updated/deleted). I'm trying to get my Question form to accept input from a check_box as to whether the question was answered (to include in the Update section).

I have read documentation on check_box [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box) and and [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box), and see that I would need `check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")`. However, I am unsure as to where I would use that in my form, and what I would pass as object_name, method and options. Any pointers will be much appreciated!

Controllers:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
  end

  def new
    @question = Question.new
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.new(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body))
    if @question.save
      flash[:notice] = "Question was saved."
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the post. Please try again."
      render :new
    end 
  end

  def show
    @question = Question.find(params[:id]) 
  end

  def edit
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    if @question.update_attributes(params.require(:question).permit(:title, :body))
      flash[:notice] = "Question was updated"
      redirect_to @question
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your post. Please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    @question.destroy
    redirect_to questions_path
    flash[:notice] = "The question has been deleted."
  end
end
```

show view:

```
<h1><%= @question.title %></h1>

<%= link_to "Edit", edit_question_path(@question), class: 'btn btn-success' %>

<%= link_to "Delete", @question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: 'btn btn-success' %>

<p><%= @question.body %></p>
```

edit view:

```
<h1>Edit and Update Question</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <p>Guidelines for questions</p>
    <ul>
      <li>Stay on topic.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <%= form_for @question do |f| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post title" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :body %>
        <%= f.text_area :body, rows: 8, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter post body" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", @question, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: 'btn btn-success' %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, for instance, you have an `answered` attribute on your `Question` model that is a boolean, then all you have to do within your `form_for` block is say `<%= f.check_box :answered %>`. It'll evaluate to a true value if it's checked, false otherwise.